# How to define a folder to search in and search for files smaller than X KB within a date range?

Tags: batch-file

I have found the following example which enables me to search for files within a certain date range which I can modify to use the variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN ('forfiles /d -24-08-2021') DO (FOR /F "delims=*" %%B IN ('forfiles /m %%A /d +01-03-2021') DO (ECHO %%B)) 2>Nul
```

I have tried to replace `(ECHO %%B)` with another example that looks for files smaller than X `Forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize LSS 120000 echo @file` into the final result:

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN ('forfiles /d -24-08-2021') DO (FOR /F "delims=*" %%B IN ('forfiles /m %%A /d +01-03-2021') DO (Forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize LSS 120000 echo @file)) 2>Nul
```

but the combination does not work and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help. Next run `forfiles /d -24-08-2021` in the command prompt window and very if the date format is correct for your user account as the date format to use depends on the country configured for the user account. If that works use in the batch file `FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I IN ('%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /d -24-08-2021 2^>nul') DO IF %%~zI LSS 120000 ECHO %%I is smaller than 120000 bytes`.

Comment: I would advise that you try to perform the task the other way around. The reason for that is the ForFiles utility essentially runs a separate cmd.exe session for every file enumerated. If you use a fast method of enumerating your files based upon sizes first, then only those would be passed through to your found example code. e.g. `For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /A:-D /O:S 2^>NUL') Do If %%~zG GEq 120000 (GoTo :EOF) Else Your found code here using "%%G" as the initial ForFiles /M option`.

Comment: Hi Compo. My first problem is that I am new to batch programming. My specific problem is that in order to be able to only evaluate files (size) of files that are generated between a certain date range I have to use two forfiles /d loops so that I can use both the forfiles /d +'date' and -'date' filter option. This works, and the file size filter algorithm also works but I cannot figure out how to combine the two algorithms so that I can present which of many files in a folder between two dates that are smaller than X kb.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear to me what you're trying to do: it seems like you want file, which are more recent than an old date and smaller than a given size, this can be achieved like this:

```
Prompt>forfiles /d +01/01/2021 /C "cmd /c if @fsize lss 120000 echo @file"

/d        : filters out the files, based on its date
if @fsize : filters out the files, based on its size
```

Comment: Dominique, the question title and code make it clear what the task is. The term 'date range' and code identifying files using both `+`, and `-` dates show that they're looking for files less than or equal to one date, AND greater than or equal to another date AND which have a reported file size less than a specified number of bytes.